# Disable gridview on checkboxlist selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a `Checkboxlist` in which Items are binded from database.

Now what I want is, whenever user checks **Registration / Conveyance Deed** value from the list, Then the `gridview` should get  disabled.

I tried with below code.

```
protected void ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "30" && strMode == "M")
    {
        GridExpInfo.AllowAddingRecords = false;
    }
    else
    {
        GridExpInfo.AllowAddingRecords = true;
    }
}
```

What happens is, it always shows the selected value of `Agreement` from the list, which is **20**

Below is the screenshot of the list

[image: Img]

**update**

ASPX:-

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

C#

```
private void BindStatus()
{
    DataTable dtstatus = new DataTable();
    OracleDataAdapter dastatus = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT lookup_code agr_type_code, meaning agr_type " +
                                                        "FROM apps.fnd_lookup_values_vl " +
                                                    "WHERE (NVL ('', territory_code) = territory_code OR territory_code IS NULL " +
                                                           ") AND lookup_type = 'XXACL_FARM_AGR_TYPE' " +
                                                       "AND (lookup_type LIKE 'XXACL_FARM_AGR_TYPE') " +
                                                       "AND (view_application_id = 0) " +
                                                       "AND (security_group_id = 0) " +
                                                     "ORDER BY 1", ObjPriCon);
    dastatus.Fill(dtstatus);
    ddlStatus.DataTextField = "agr_type";
    ddlStatus.DataValueField = "agr_type_code";
    ddlStatus.DataSource = dtstatus;
    ddlStatus.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You want disable only adding new rows?

Comment: @mww: yes, I want to disable _only_ that

Comment: Please show also how you create  checkboxlist

Comment: @mww: see the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
    protected void myCheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool enableGrid = true;
        foreach (ListItem listItem in ddlStatus.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Value == "30" && listItem.Selected == true)
            {
                enableGrid = false;
            }
        }

        if (enableGrid == true)
        {
            //enable grid and/or row inserts here
            Label1.Text = "enabled";
        }
        else
        {
            //disable grid and/or row inserts here
            Label1.Text = "disabled";
        }
    }
```

Comment: liked the logic, let me try and check..!

Answer (score 2):

You can set property `AllowUserToAddRows` to false inside code as shown below.

```
this.yourGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.BindDataGridView();
```

And use `ForEach` loop for checking your condition. Now you check all selected items not only first selected.

```
 protected void ddlStatus_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem li in ddlStatus.Items)
        {
            if (li.Value == "30" && strMode == "M")
            {
                GridExpInfo.AllowUserToAddRows  = false;
            }
            else
            {
                GridExpInfo.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            }
        }
```

You can also use LINQ for checking it.

```
   protected void ddlStatus_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (strMode == "M")
        {
            var disable = (from ListItem item in ddlStatus.Items.OfType<ListItem>()
                where item.Selected
                where item.Value == "30"
                select int.Parse(item.Value)).Any();

             if (disable)
            {
                GridExpInfo.AllowUserToAddRows  = false;
            }
            else
            {
                GridExpInfo.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: did you read my question, I just want it on `Registration / Conveyance Deed` condition which is not getting fired. Only the `Agreement` condition is fired..

Comment: when I add the else part with `true` it doesnt works, but when I remove the else part it works well..!!